# после refresh браузера крашится приложение

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router-dom, router

При refresh браузера на главной странице (http://localhost:3000/posts-list) все нормально обновляется, после перехода на следующую страницу приложения (http://localhost:3000/posts-list/profile/1) если сделать refresh браузера то приложение крашится, эту ссылку если вставить в новой вкладке браузера она также не работатет. Кто разбирается подскажите как починить.

`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className={style.App}>
      <header className={style.header}>
        <h1 className={style.header__text}>Blog</h1>
      </header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={"/posts-list/profile/:id"} element={<ProfileContainer />} />
        <Route path={"/posts-list/profile/:id/posts/"} element={<PostsContainer />} />
        <Route path={"/posts-list/profile/:id/posts/:postId/"} element={<CommentsContainer />} />
        <Route path="/posts-list" element={<UsersList />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`

вот эта компонента не срабатывает

`

```
const ProfileContainer = () => {
      let params = useParams();
      const { usersList, postsList } = useSelector((state) => {
        return { usersList: state.usersList, postsList: 
                 state.postsList };
      });
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requestPosts());
      }, []);
    
      const findPosts = [];
      postsList.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.userId === Number(params.id)) {
          findPosts.push(element);
        }
      });
      const userFind = usersList.find((user) => {
        return user.id === Number(params.id);
      });
     return <Profile userFind={userFind} userId={params.id} findPosts={findPosts} />;
    };
```

`

Comment: весь эпичный код здесь ->  https://github.com/PortfolioShow/posts-list

Answer (score 0):

Помог человек из https://qna.habr.com/q/1159504, его комментарий ниже:

> При перезагрузке страницы usersList пуст и нигде не запрашивается. А если сначала зайдём по адресу post-list, то этот список загрузится и будет доступен для перехода в профиль. Попробуй добавить ещё и запрос на список юзеров при маунте в profile container.
> Так же надо добавить проверку в Profile.jsx

```js
const previewPosts = findPosts.slice(0, 3);

  if (!userFind) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }
```